# Is there a way to increase field limit in CRM?

Tags: database, dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm work many times on CRM Online which causes this issue, and then I have to do create entity relationship to get thorugh the issue.
So,
Is there a way I can increase the field limit in CRM form while doing customization?

Version: Any Online Version

Comment: Any reason why you can't increase the field length through the default solution?

Comment: @Kye I didn't mean for field length. I mean for total number of fields in a form.

Comment: and which is the limit you reached?

Comment: @GuidoPreite 1024 field limit in CRM form, actually that's not the limitation of CRM but SQL.

Comment: i know the CRM field limits, if you think it's reasonable to put around 1000 fields inside a single entity then good luck with your CRM implementation

Comment: I agree with Guido, we have a very extended implementation with salesorder and with the native fields we don't reach 250 fields.

Comment: @GuidoPreite Well, the solution is working good without performance issue, sometime if need some modification then have to use system field or negotiate with other field and delete one to add priority one or use entity-relationship, so wondering if somehow we can increase that limit which doesn't require any extra steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as noted in the comments this is a limit in SQL.

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Quite a good discussion here, [Best Practices - Maximum number of fields on an entity?](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/124122)

*(Though why you would want to put 1000 fields on a single entity is beyond me. Would be interested to know your solution for curiosities sake).*

Comment: to answer for your curiosity, the solution contains 2-3 custom entities of this size, apart from that all other are obvious size which everybody considure standard. And to design that entity we need to use lots of webresources and Silverlight components and images. so when we need more fields we either uses system fields or manage to do something with webresources.

Answer (score 0):

This field limit for the database is not limited to SQL but also affect to other Database too so incase we need to reuse the same data in other databases then there may be the issues.

So now this limit makes sense to me, though still wondering all columns are stored in single column or span across rows like chain of columns, as like Oracle does.

I know oracle support 255 columns in a single row and upto 1000 in table, but if you got more then 255 then it spans the remaining to next corresponding row accordingly.